# Excel VBA - How to Add Names into ComboBox while Checking If the Input Is Already in the ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm new to VBA and I'm quite a noob at it. So I wanted the user, whenever he puts a name into the ComboBox, it gets added to it, however, I also want to check if the input is already in that ComboBox and if it is, then I do not want to add it. This is my code so far, no errors were given to me but then when I put a name on the ComboBox, it doesn't get added to the ComboBox.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Enter()

Dim nameStr As String
Set nameArray = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")


nameStr = ComboBox2.Value
'nameArray.Add (nameStr)

For Each nameItm In nameArray
    If nameItm = ComboBox2.Value Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        nameArray.Add (nameStr)
        ComboBox2.AddItem (nameStr)
    End If
Next nameItm  
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you initially populating the combobox?

Comment: @norie The name of the ComboBox is actually "ComboBox2" (Sorry, I haven't really edited the name yet) and I use "ComboBox2.AddItem" to add the input to the ComboBox,. Also, I added this array list named "nameArray" so I would add the inputs there and use it to check if the input has already been inputted before.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do here? Is this combobox on a sheet or userform? Are you going to store the names entered by the user somewhere other than in the combobox list so they can be used again?

Comment: @norie This ComboBox is in a UserForm. I think I will store them just in the ComboBox. I just want the user to keep track of the inputs.

Comment: Won't the inputs be "deleted" every time you close the userform if you dont store them in a sheet?

Comment: What norie is probably looking for is that if you store the values in a sheet, you can look through that list of inputs so find any duplicates.